# OLEDB Error in Visual Studio 2015 not in 2012

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, oledb

The following code works when I run it in Visual Studio 2012, but not in Visial Studio 2015:

```
 Dim strconn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

    strconn += "Data Source=" & FileNameAndPath & ";"

    If Has_Headers Then
        strconn += "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"""
    Else
        strconn += "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;"""
    End If

    Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strconn)
    dt = New DataTable()

    ' create SQL to connect to correct table

    Dim mysql As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & SheetName & "$]"
    Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mysql, Conn)

    Try
        Conn.Open()
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        Conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        dt = New DataTable()
        MessageBox.Show("Error loading data from " & FileNameAndPath & ". Please check it is the correct format")
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

The error occurs when it attempts the connection.

The error is:

> Exception thrown at 0x746FB802 (KernelBase.dll) in TestProgram.exe: 0xE0000002 (parameters: 0x80004004).

I'm using target framework .NET framework 4.5.2 in both 
target CPU x86.

Comment: Are you using AnyCPU configuration or x64? If so try with x86 to see if it is a driver version issue. Also, there should be more to the exception message than that.

Comment: I'm using x86 in both.  The program crashed as soon as it hits the conn.open, which doesn't trip the try catch.  I also get an error 'mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2128)\OLEAUT32.dll!75E45072: (caller: 75E4FE4F) ReturnHr(1) tid(3460) 8002801D Library not registered.' coming up before the exception mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this indirectly.
I reinstalled the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010, no change.
I created a new test project in VS 2015 with only the code above, it worked.
Given that this didn't appear to be a common problem across the internet I decided it must be down to a corrupted file.
I deleted the module containing the failing code and created a new one, with the same code copied and pasted in. That solved the problem.